# Распаковка архива в node.js

Tags: node.js, gzip

Добрый день.

Ищу возможность распаковать архивы gz, созданные сторонней программой, в node.js.
Модуль tar.gz не распознает архив. Модуль zlib не устанавливается.

Что не так с zlib? Есть ли другие варианты?

Спасибо

P.S. Вопрос снят. Оказалось, что в node.js уже есть [встроенная поддержка zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830995/npm-install-node-waf-not-found-what-to-do).